# Mass Cane stalk is covered in roots

Tags: plant-health

I found this mass cane on the curb 2+ years ago, and have kept it alive and repotted it a year ago.

For a while it hadn’t produced any new growth but hasn’t shown any signs of distress so I figured it was just hanging out. I looked into propagating it today, and I realized the bark on the bottom half was completely loose and coming off easily. But! The dead bottom half of the stalk had roots growing all the way up (underneath the bark) to the healthy part of the plant!

I couldn’t find anything about this anywhere and though I’ve cut a stem to propagate I’m wondering if I can leave most of the rest of the plant and see what happens. I’m so proud of it for surviving. I think it stopped producing leaf growth because it was working so hard to grow these roots!

Does anybody have experience with this?

[image: stalk of mass cane exposed with roots growing]

Comment: @kevinskio (don't have permissions to comment yet) Thank you for affirming how weird it is! I've been watering it with a self-watering stake system for a long time to make sure it doesn't get over-watered. I wonder if that helped it survive this way? I think I'm going to remove a little more from the bottom and let it ride. This cane is over 5 feet tall so there's a lot of roots to work with.

Answer (score 1):

It's unusual to see this. Normally when they are overwatered the top stays alive for the longest time and the roots and circulatory structures die back.  You notice that it's dead when the bark becomes loose and can peel off.
This one appears to have grown new roots from the living part on the top down to the soil.

Seeing as these plants are propagated by cutting them into lengths you could try cutting the live part off, trying to keep the roots and planting but this is quite delicate.

I realize this is a rescue mission but most people would put this one back on the curb as new ones are available readily.